# Orbits of $SO(3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

**Disclaimer:** this question had several edit; this one treats the case $k=\mathbb{R}$, while I'll post another one for the complex case.

Consider the action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$, with homogeneous coordinates $x_0,x_1,x_2$, of the form
$$SO(3)\times\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^2$$
$$(A,p)\mapsto Ap.$$ I'd like to understand what are thr orbits of this action, and understand if the action is transitive, that is $SO(3)\simeq \mathbb{P}^2$ that is, since $SO(3)/SO(3)_p\simeq SO(3)p$, I'd like to study $$SO(3)/SO(3)_p.$$
For doing so I considered for simplicity the poitn $p=(1:0:0)$, and I've found that
$$SO(3)_p=\{A\in SO(3)\mid \text{the first columns of $A$ is equal to $p$}\}.$$
In order to conclude, I should show that given a point $y\in \mathbb{P}^2$, there exists a matrix $B\in SO(3)$ such that $Bp=y$, i.e. the first column of $B$ is equal to $y$. Unfortunately now I'm stuck, because I don't know how to create a matrix out of simply a column $y$.

Answer (score 1):

You need a matrix $B$ such that $Bp$ is proportional to $y$ (thinking of $y$ as a vector in $\Bbb R^3$). So the first step is to replace $y$ with $y/\|y\|$, so that it's a unit vector. Then you need a rotation matrix whose first column is $y$. The other two columns must be orthogonal to $y$, and they have to be positively oriented. So here's a construction:

Let the smallest entry of $y$, in absolute value, be the $i$th. Let $w = e_i$. Compute $$
v = w - w \cdot y
$$
which is orthogonal to $y$ (why can't it be zero? That's an exercise for you), and then let
$$
u  = v / \| v \|
$$
which is a unit vector orthogonal to $y$. Then let $B$ be a matrix with columns $y, u, $ and $y \times u$.

But note that this works for every point $y$, not just those on your curve $C$, so I don't really understand how this addresses your problem. I've probably misunderstood something.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't understand: are you saying that, given a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$, its orbit is always all of $\mathbb{P}^2$? because I was asked to show that given a point inside the quadric, its orbit was only the quadric (intuitively you cannot "escape" from the curve), so there's something unclear, I'll surely misunderstood something...anyway thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps I don't know what $\Bbb P^2$ means. For you, is it real-projective 2-space, or complex projective 2-space? If it's the former, then the action of $SO(3)$ does in fact have all of $P^2$ as the orbit of any single point, and has a circle subgroup of $SO(3)$ as the stabilizer of any single point. Proof of the orbit claim: Point your finger in some direction. Now point in a different direction. Unless your finger deformed, you just rotated an arbitrary direction to another arbitrary direction.

Comment: You absolutely right, I completely forgot to specify I was working on the complex projective $2$-space, I am sorry and I'll edit it

Comment: Aha! OK, well, my construction (applied to real vectors $y$) produces an $S^2$ (i.e. $\Bbb C \Bbb P^1$)-worth of vectors in $\Bbb P^2$, which is good. But it does *not* produce the vector $\pmatrix{1\\i\\1}$ which lies on your curve, since the only vectors it produces have all three entries being real. Is it possible that $SO(3)$ also means something different? Because otherwise, I don't see a way to get where you want to go. In particular, nothing in your description involves the quadric $C$, so if you had another quadric $C' \ne C$ containing $p$, we'd have $SO(3)p = C = C' = SO(3)p$!

Comment: Oh god I'm so sorry, you're so kind to help me but I realize I surely didn't write properly the question: the problem may lie on the fact that $SO(3)=\{A\in Gl(3,\mathbb{C})\mid A^t Q A= Q, \text{ } \det(A)=1\}$, where $Q$ is the $3\times 3$-matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
that is, the bilinear form corresponding on the quadric $C$... since you've been very kind, I'll post now another question, with major details, and I'll leave this one (accepted), in the case of $\mathbb{R}$... thanks again, I'll post here the link, if you want to answer it!

Comment: This is the link to the new question, where I tried to write everything...if you still want to help me it would be great!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807016/quadric-preserved-by-the-so3-action-on-mathbbp6